# Elastic search on openshift

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, deployment, openshift

I have been trying to deploy elastic search on openshift . I am new to it and have no idea about the configurations and the process for the same .

Can someone guide me on the same?

Comment: Hi, this article is a very good starting point: https://www.gronau-it-cloud-computing.de/should-we-run-elasticsearch-on-openshift/